# find id equal to a number using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Click on button with `class="a"`, increases the `counter`.

How can I:

1. Find div with `class="b"` (not "b"'s child)  with an id equal to that counter
2. Remove class `hidden` from it
3. Change the hash by adding `counter` value at the end of it (without reloading the page)

Here's what I tried:

**HTML**

```html
<a class="a" id="0">link</a>
<div class="b hidden" id="1">1</div>
<div class="b hidden" id="2">2</div>
<div class="b hidden" id="3">3</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var counter = 0;

$('.a').click(function () {
    counter++;

    var current_id = counter;

    //check to fin ids = counter to remove class hidden from them    
    $('.b[id="' + current_id + '"]').removeClass('hidden'); // not work
}, function () {

});
```

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/3/)

Comment: Can you provide fiddle please?

Comment: I suggest you make attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: It seems like your steps translate into obvious jQuery code, please show what you've tried and we can help you fix the problems. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I added the link to jsfiddle

Comment: what for is the second `function` in your fiddle?

Comment: One problem is that the [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method does not accept a second handler function. (Perhaps you were thinking of [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).) [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`Working Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/KFUVq/11/)***

```
$('.a').click(function () {
    counter++;
    var current_id = counter;
    $('.counter').text(current_id);//show the counter value
    $('.b').addClass('hidden');//hide all  
    $('.b[id="' + current_id + '"]').removeClass('hidden');//show the required
});
```

---

1. anchor tags **without href** not a good practice<sup>(didn't that without `href` the anchor tag can be clicked, thanks to ***@showdev*** for the valuable comment)</sup>
2. you didn't defined what you wanted to do using `hidden` class.. Supposing from the name, I guess you *do not want to display elements with class hidden*

And just a suggestion using the code within `$(document).ready();` would be safer...

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Incidentally, when using a `click()` handler, `<a>` tags don't need an `href` in order to be clickable. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Er2CR/).